# How can I implement a trait on external struct from a package?

Tags: rust

There is this package called `eddsa` that has a struct defined like this `pub struct PrivateKey<E: JubjubEngine>(pub E::Fs);`

I need to print a struct but I can't because it uses this package struct and doesn't have copy, clone or debug traits implemented.

How can I override, or extend the trait from this struct from an external package?

If I wrap inside another struct, still fires the error
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: You need to implement the trait manually for the wrapper struct.

Comment: You will not be able to implement `Copy`, even with a wrapper struct. `Clone` would be your next best option.